# What defines the currency of an Ethereum wallet?

Tags: wallets

I'm new here. I'm building a wallet app using vanityeth to generate addresses. I want to generate a wallet for Ethereum and wallets for some other ERC20 tokens. After doing some research, and please correct me if I'm wrong, but I found that an ethereum wallet generated with vanityeth can hold ERC20 tokens, but not more than one type of token at the same wallet.

So what defines what type of token a wallet stores?

Do I need to specify this before generating the wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> an ethereum wallet generated with vanityeth can hold ERC20 tokens, but not more than one type of token at the same wallet

This isn't true. Any address can own any ERC20 tokens.

An ERC20 token is really just a smart contract maintaining a mapping of addresses to balances. Each contract is independent and has no way of knowing what other kinds of tokens an address "owns". If you're a developer, you might want to read https://ethereum.org/token to get the basic idea.

(I suppose there could always be a limitation on the wallet software you're using in that it will only show you one ERC20 token at a time? Just a guess; if you have a source for that information, I'd be happy to take a look.)

Comment: It's not an online source, just some more experienced people told me that. So you're saying I can have one ETH address that holds 4 or 5 different ERC20 Tokens and Ethereum at the same address?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: this is good news, do you have a source where I can read more about this?

Comment: Edited with a little more info. I hope that helps!